# SpringMVC Validator Needs to be Also Used Remotely, not just on immediate screen

Tags: spring, validation, spring-mvc

I ran into this issue: our SpringMVC Validator validates a form (the normal case); this works OK.

Also, in a separate use case, it needs to be called remotely from a different location to put an exclamation point icon ("!") in front of some element on a different screen that refers to that form object.

I can validate any object of the class supported by the Validator, but the issue is how to add errors:

1) On the one hand, this Validator should reject errors for the path on its screen when it's used in the normal case:

```
errors.rejectValue("object.field.path", "errorCode", args, defaultMessage);
```

2) On the other hand, this will fail when it's called remotely, this path doesn't exist because the form is different. The only thing I can do here is something that doesn't depend on paths,

```
errors.rejectValue("errorCode");
```

Ideally the same Validator should respond to both cases... It should tell me there are validation errors on the form. In Case A it's specific, in Case B it's general. Can anyone advise how to approach this?

**UPDATE** The issue is general Bean Validation vs. GUI Validation. I understand is that SpringMVC's Validators are strongly tied to the GUI. But we also need a generic way to validate data beans, and hopefully reuse that. Or maybe I can create a "mock" BindingResult/JSP?